# Mistakenly gave 'git reset --hard origin/master'. How to undo this?

Tags: git, git-merge

After that When i run this 'git reset HEAD@{1}' It shows 'Unstaged changes after reset:' followed by all my files including lost files. What should be my next command to recover the lost files?

Comment: That was not matched with my issue.

Comment: You can recover your commited but not pushed changes using reflog. If the changes weren't commited, it is not possible to recover them using git.
You can get more info about reflog in the linked questions or in https://git-scm.com/docs/git-reflog

Comment: Thanks for the response @Fede. I got recovered my files by using the following commands,
'git reset HEAD@{1}' and
'git add .'